# Alignment of multiple elements with indentation

Tags: align

I'm trying to typeset an optimization problem that uses variable conditioned constraints (vif) in combination with normal constraints. My current syntax (of a part of the problem) is

```
\begin{align*}
\max \sum_{i \in I} z_i \\
\text{subject to} \\
 x_i^0 &= x_i^{\text{start}}  &&\forall i \in I, \\
 l_i^t + r_i^t + c_i^t &= 1  &&\forall t = 0,...,N-1, i \in I, \\
\text{vif } v_i^t = 1 \text{ then} \\
 x_j^t - x_i^t &\leq \epsilon \\
\text{else} \\
 x_j^t - x_i^t &\geq \epsilon + \hat{\epsilon}\\
\text{end} &&&\forall t=0,...,N-1, i,j \in I: i < j, \\
 k_i^t &= \sum_{j \in I \setminus \{i\}} v_{\min(i,j),max(i,j)}+1+c_i^t  &&\forall t=0,...,N-1, i \in I, \\
\end{align*}
```

which displays 
[image: misplaced end and else]

I would like to have the `else` and the `end` aligned to the left (like the `vif` is already) while maintaining the slight indent for the line underneath the `vif`. If I try to put an ampersand in front of the `else` or `end` however, I cannot manage to align the other equations around the `=` or `\geq` signs properly. A satisfactory result would look roughly like this (I edited the picture) [image: edited picture]

How can such indentation be achieved while keeping the constraints aligned in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick fix is to make the two lines for `if` and `else` have the same width as that for the line `\text{vif } v_i^t = 1 \text{ then}`. You can use `makebox` for this. `calc` package is also required to allow `\widthof` to calculate the width automatically.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}    
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\adjleft}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{$\text{vif } v_i^t = 1 \text{ then}$}][l]{#1}}

\begin{align*}
\max \sum_{i \in I} z_i \\
\text{subject to} \\
 x_i^0 &= x_i^{\text{start}}  &&\forall i \in I, \\
 l_i^t + r_i^t + c_i^t &= 1  &&\forall t = 0,...,N-1, i \in I, \\
\text{vif } v_i^t = 1 \text{ then} \\
 x_j^t - x_i^t &\leq \epsilon \\
\adjleft{else}  \\
 x_j^t - x_i^t &\geq \epsilon + \hat{\epsilon}\\
\adjleft{end} &&&\forall t=0,...,N-1, i,j \in I: i < j, \\
 k_i^t &= \sum_{j \in I \setminus \{i\}} v_{\min(i,j),max(i,j)}+1+c_i^t  &&\forall t=0,...,N-1, i \in I, \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]